# Как в GridLayout сделать так, что бы все ячейки полностью разделили между собой все доступное пространство?

Tags: android, android-layout

Мне нужно, что бы все кнопки были одинаковыми по размеру и занимали все свободное место, но не хочу указывать явно размер, что бы на разных экранах все нормально смотрелось.
[image: Скрин]

Comment: попробуй всем сделать одинаковый вес weight

Comment: Не работает, тогда пропадают кнопки

Comment: Оформите код разметки в виде текста, а не скриншота

Answer (score 2):

Для этого есть параметр `stretchMode`.  Используется в случае, когда вы указываете ширину столбца и кол-во ставите в режим `AUTO_FIT`. по умолчанию: `STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH` – свободное пространство используется столбцами

Comment: Параметр чего? Можно по подробнее

Comment: Я перепутал. Мне сначала на картинке показалось, что вы `GridView` используете. а для `GridLayout` попробуйте `android:layout_gravity="center"`